# Universal app and landscape orientation for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape, portrait, ios-universal-app

I want to design a universal app that I'd want to support just portrait orientation. It's weird because Xcode allows you to select portrait orientation only in the target's Deployment Info settings (and in Info.plist), but reading the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html), in the section regarding the launch images, I've found this:

> You must provide at least one launch image. Typically, an iPhone app includes at least one launch image in portrait orientation; an iPad app includes at least one launch image in portrait orientation and at least one launch image in landscape orientation.

Does that mean that you have to provide a launch image in landscape orientation even if you only support portrait orientation? Or is it required to support landscape orientation in iPad?

Thanks

**EDIT:** It looks like it is not required to support both portrait and landscape orientations in iPad, though strongly recommended. However, it looks like, if an orientation supported, also the opposite one should be (portrait and upside-down, for instance). Is it required then to provide both launch images? (portrait and upside-down). Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It is strongly recommended that your application support all orientations. This includes portrait, portrait upside-down, landscape left and landscape right.  iPad apps that require an orientation must support both variants of that orientation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1588/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know that it should be recommended in iPad, but I was told to support portrait only... my question is if it is possible in iPad to do that: is it only a recommendation, or is it required to support both portrait and landscape?

Comment: if you do support only portrait your app may be rejected from apple app store. they are doesn't apporvel

Comment: Thanks. Is there any Apple's document where I could find that?

Comment: if your application supports portrait, then it should support both UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait and UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

Comment: So, no need to support landscape though recommended... what is mandatory is to support upside-down orientation then, right? Thanks

Comment: yep no need to support landscape

Comment: Another question comes to me... I've seen two different keys in Info.plist but just to make sure... Supporting portrait and upside-down orientations in iPad does not imply that I need to also support upside-down orientation in iPhone, does it?

Comment: Not like that. it is for your wish

Comment: Thanks again. What about the landscape orientation launch image mentioned in the interface guidelines?

Comment: Launch in your supported orientation, regardless of the current device orientation.