# ios Missing orientation support (globally) after using the application

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, rotation, orientation

My application for iPad uses device orientation "Portrait" and "Required Full Screen" settings. When the application is running or in background, device orientation support does not work. Home screen in portrait mode only and does not respond to rotation. 
On my own iPad2/IOS 9.3.5 it works fine, but the customer found this bug on 3 of their devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Universal app and landscape orientation for iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167011/universal-app-and-landscape-orientation-for-ipad)

Comment: Thank you. How to be if the design of the application is not compatible with landscape orientation?

Comment: Then why would you want it to respond to rotation?

Comment: I can not understand why the home screen does not rotate when my application is in the background

Comment: Do you have the device rotation lock on?

Comment: Yes, device rotation is not locked. And I can not repeat this bug on my device. Probably need to take a new iPad model and test.